# Closed form from $y\left(1-\exp(-x/y)\right) = f(x)g(y)$

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus

I want to write the equation on the left into a function such that it can be written as equation on the right $$y\left(1-\exp(-x/y)\right)=f(x)g(y)$$

So far my idea is to use power series of $$\exp\left(\frac{x}{y}\right) = 1 + \left(-\frac{x}{y}\right) + \frac{1}{2}\left(\frac{x}{y}\right)^2 - \frac{1}{6}\left(\frac{x}{y}\right)^3 + \dots $$ and only use until the second or third power and get the form of:
$$
y\left[ \left(\frac{x}{y}\right) - \frac{1}{2}\left(\frac{x}{y}\right)^2 + \frac{1}{6}\left(\frac{x}{y}\right)^3 \right] = x - \frac{x^2}{2y} + \frac{x^3}{6y^2}
$$
But still can't have the form of $f(x)g(y)$.

And the alternative form I could think is:
$$
\exp\left[ y \left(1-\exp(-x/y)\right)\right] = \frac{\exp(y)}{\exp(y\exp(-x)^{1/y})}
$$
But still can't get the form of $f(x)g(y)$

Comment: I do not think that $y\left(1-\exp(-x/y)\right)$ can be written as $f(x)g(y)$.

Comment: as the others have pointed out this seems futile, my question is why do you want to do so?

Comment: In what context did this arise? I don't think it is a pre-calculus course. I assume that there must be more information like y is a linear function, etc.

Answer (score 2):

You are having difficulty because it is not possible.

**Claim:** $y(1-\exp(-x/y))$ cannot be written as $f(x)g(y)$.

**Proof:** We prove by contradiction. Let $h(x,y) = y (1-\exp(-x/y))$. Suppose $h(x,y)=f(x)g(y)$ for some functions $f,g$. Then, for all $x_1,x_2,y_1,y_2$ we would have  $$
h(x_1,y_1)h(x_2,y_2) =f(x_1)g(y_1)f(x_2)g(y_2) = f(x_1)g(y_2)f(x_2)g(y_1)= h(x_1,y_2)h(x_2,y_1)
$$
by commutativity of multiplication. However, if we compare $h(1,1)h(2,2)$ with $h(1,2)h(2,1)$ we find them to be unequal $$
h(1,1)h(2,2)=2(1-1/e)^2 \ne h(1,2)h(2,1) = 2(1-\exp(-1/2))(1-\exp(-2))
$$
If you don't have a calculator handy to check that these expressions are unequal, you can observe that their equality would make the transcendental number $1/\sqrt{e}$ satisfy the nontrivial polynomial equation $$
(1-t^2)^2 = (1-t)(1-t^4)
$$
Therefore our assumption that $h(x,y)=f(x)g(y)$ for some functions $f$ and $g$ is wrong.

Comment: This is hard to understand!