# Closed form of $\frac{y}{x}(1-\exp(-\frac{x}{y}) = f(x)g(y)$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

How to write this equation $$\frac{y}{x}\left(1-\exp\left(-\frac{x}{y}\right)\right) = f(x)g(y)$$
I tried to expand $\exp{\left(-\frac{x}{y}\right)} = 1 - \left(\frac{x}{y}\right) + \frac{1}{2}\left(\frac{x}{y}\right)^2 - \dots$ and have this following result :
$$1 - \frac{1}{2!}\left(\frac{x}{y}\right) + \frac{1}{3!}\left(\frac{x}{y}\right)^2 - \dots$$
I tried to make it into this series  but stuck here. Any help ?

Comment: Have you tried to apply the method from the answer to your previous question https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4611469/42969 ?

Comment: Update your old question instead of making a new one please.